# Timestamp Equation - Firebase Database + Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning about swift coding and firebase. I am trying out this code which in theory does make sense however I do not achieve the desired result. It seems as though my math is wrong however, I think I may be formatting the code incorrectly.

Essentially, a post is saved to the firebase rtd with a timestamp. I am wanting for the post to be deleted if a minute has passed after the post has been uploaded.

```
let postFinally = Posts(timeStamp: timeStamp as! Double?)

let cutTime = 1.0 * 60.0 * 1000.0
                    
let postTime = postFinally.timeStamp as Any as! Double
  
   if postTime > postTime + cutTime {
      print("delete")
   } else {
       print("not delete")
   }     
 // Timestamp derived from the firebase database. Ie, 1633590010833.0
```

Am I formatting the code wrong? It always returns 'do not delete' even after the desired time.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Edit Updated Equation However Does Not Seem To Work. I choose the cut time as a hour however, it still executes 'delete' right away.

```
let postFinally = Posts(timeStamp: timeStamp as! Double?)

let cutTime = 1.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 1000.0
                    
let postTime = postFinally.timeStamp as Any as! Double
  
   if postTime < postTime + cutTime {
      print("delete")
   } else {
       print("not delete")
   }     
 // Timestamp derived from the firebase database. Ie, 1633590010833.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here check it

```
if postFinally.timeStamp! > postFinally.timeStamp! + cutTime {
   print("delete")
}
```

You have added something in postFinally.timeStamp, so how postFinally.timeStamp is greater than postFinally.timeStamp + cutTime ?

```
postFinally.timeStamp + cutTime > postFinally.timeStamp
```

So i think your code will execute else block.

**OR**

You can get the posted time as string, then you can easily get time difference in seconds. Here is the example

```
guard let postedDate = timeString.toDate() else { return ""} 
let timeDifferenceSecond = Date().timeIntervalSince(postedDate)
```

Comment: It's strange because when I do do that, it executes the first block irrespective of the actual time. I will edit the answer above and give you a visual depiction of what I mean. Thank you for your input though I really appreciate it

Comment: I have added another solution, please check.